# What is a HomeGroup?

Tags: windows-7, windows, homegroup

I cannot seem to understand what exactly a HomeGroup *is*.

What is a HomeGroup, and how is it different from a Workgroup or a Domain?
(I already understand the last 2.)

Why would I want to use a HomeGroup instead of a Workgroup/Domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm no pro but I find in practicality that HomeGroup works better than the other two. I would spend hours setting up workgroups and domains and what not just to get two computers to send files to each other. Now I can send music to a player and my brother can easily browse my picture collection via homegroup using a simple password. If I had to think of it as anything, I would just think of it as workgroup 2.0

If you want you can read this hefty debate on this forum about HomeGroups vs WorkGroups, but from my point of view and my use of it in real life it's just an upgrade of workgroups from XP (a really really good one use-wise)

http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/27725-homegroup-vs-workgroup.html

Comment: It was to make home networking easier for those who have no networking background or experience, if you know how to set up networks, you won't like homegroups. I still prefer the "work network" over the "home network" when setting up a W7 pc.

Comment: See I did not know that. I had the worst times setting those up. It's good to hear someone has a different view on it :)